# Detecting app engine datastore model attribute changes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

**How to trigger a method call every time a datastore entity attribute changes?**

One way to do this I looked into was [monkeypatching db.Model.put](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Pre--and-post--put-hooks-for-Datastore-models). That involved overriding the put method. While that allows me to react to every put(), it wasn't clear how I would detect if the address attribute has changed, since self.address would be already set in the beginning of .put().

Elaboration:

I have users and each user has a physical address.

```
class User(db.Model):
    ...
    address = db.StringProperty() # for example "2 Macquarie Street, Sydney"
    ...
```

I would like to verify that the entered addresses are correct. For this I have an expensive address checking function (it contacts a remote API) and a boolean field.

```
class User(db.Model):
    ...
    address = db.StringProperty()
    address_is_valid = db.BooleanProperty(default=False)

    def address_has_changed(self):
        self.address_is_valid = False
        Task(
            url = "/check_address", # this would later set .address_is_valid 
            params = {
                'user' : self.key()
            }
        ).add()
    ...
```

But how can I get the address_has_changed method to trigger every time the address changes, without having to explicitly call it everywhere?

```
# It should work when changing an address
some_user = User.all().get()
some_user.address = "Santa Claus Main Post Office, FI-96930 Arctic Circle"
some_user.put()

# It should also work when multiple models are changed
...
db.put([some_user, another_user, yet_another_user])

# It should even work when creating a user
sherlock = User(address='221 B Baker St, London, England')
sherlock.put() # this should trigger address_has_changed
```

Comment: Are you committed to using `db` if not see Paul Collingwoods answer below and switch to ndb - which IMO is a superior api to db having large codebases in both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright this might be 2 years too late, but here it is anyway you can always create class local variables in the `__init()__` method that store old values and while you're calling the put method compare the values from these old variables.

```
class User(db.Model):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._old_address = self.address

    address = db.StringProperty() 

    def put(self, **kwargs):
        if self._old_address != self.address:
             # ...
             # do your thing
             # ...

        super(User, self).put(**kwargs)
```

Comment: This pattern won't work as any model that is loaded from the datastore (via `Key.get()` or a query) will be constructed via an empty `init()` call and then the data is populated via another method (see `Model._from_pb()`). So the `_old` variable will be `None` in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

What about a [Hook](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#hooks)?

> NDB offers a lightweight hooking mechanism. By defining a hook, an
>   application can run some code before or after some type of operations;
>   for example, a Model might run some function before every get().

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Friend(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()

  def _pre_put_hook(self):
    # inform someone they have new friend

  @classmethod
  def _post_delete_hook(cls, key, future):
    # inform someone they have lost a friend

f = Friend()
f.name = 'Carole King'
f.put() # _pre_put_hook is called
fut = f.key.delete_async() # _post_delete_hook not yet called
fut.get_result() # _post_delete_hook is called
```

You could build in some further logic so that the original and new versions of the address are checked, and if they differ then run the expensive operation, otherwise just save.

Comment: The original question is using db.  If they can change to ndb then this is the correct strategy.  Other wise the article the question refers to by Nick Johnson is probably the best strategy.

Comment: How would the original and new versions of the address be checked? It doesn't seem that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use a python property. This makes it easy to call address_has_changed whenever it is actually changed.

Comment: Except you would only want to call that method when you call `put()` not when the property has changed.  There could be situations where put() isn't reached.  You could use this strategy to set a flag, that the property has changed, and then a pre_put_hook can check that flag to see if the `address_has_changed` method needs to be called.

Comment: However it does create a somewhat confusing api, because you can't use normal python property descripters to hide the db Model property.  So you would end up with an `address` Model property, and a python property called something else. And then you must make sure you call the "something else property" when you update the address rather than assigning to the address property.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Nick's article you refer too or `ndb` hooks solve the problem of tracking explicit changes in entities, they just make it easier to solve.

You would normally call your `address_is_changed` method inside the pre put hook rather all over the code base when you call put().

I have code in place that uses the these hook strategies to create audit trails of every change to a record,

However your code doesn't actually detect a change to the address.

You should consider changing to `ndb`, then use a `post_get hook` (to squirrel away orginal property values you wish to check - for instance in a session or request object) then use `pre_put_hook` to check the current property vs the orginal value, to see if you should then take any action, then call you a`ddress_has_changed` method. You can use this strategy using `db` (by following Nicks article) but then you have to do a lot more heavy lifting yourself.